# Replace a string with an integer value keeping the string length fixed

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns in SQL Server Table, one is Id and other one is Number, for example if Ids are as follows: 1189, 758, 756, I want a User defined or system defined function, that can generate numbers as: T01189, T00758, T00756.

I want to keep this function either as Default field or add it to trigger - soon after the record inserted, you can suggest me which one is better also.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a padding trick here:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    'T' + RIGHT('0000' + Id, 5) AS Number
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: But this is giving me the correct answer maybe because of different DB or version: select 'T' + RIGHT('00000'+CAST(InspectionItemId AS VARCHAR(5)),6), InspectionItemId, InspectionItemNumber 
from InspectionItems where CaseId=293 order by 1 desc

Comment: Oh...I am assuming that `Id` is text already.  If not, then yes, you would need to cast it first, as you have pointed out.